# Does St Paul make contradicting statements in 1 Cor 11:17-19?

Tags: 1-corinthians, pauline-epistles

We read in 1 Cor 11:17-19:

> In the following directives I have no praise for you, for your meetings do more harm than good.  In the first place, I hear that when you come together as a church, there are divisions among you, and to some extent I believe it.  No doubt there have to be differences among you to show which of you have God’s approval.

< Here, St Paul acknowledges that differences help in manifestation of God's approval. At the same time he reprimands Corinthians for the divisions in their get- together. My question is : Does St Paul make contradicting statements in 1 Cor 11:17-19 ?

Comment: Paul is his name.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see this as contradiction but as an expression that many things in the social life of the church play both positive and negative roles. Paul is "thinking out loud" about a situation, in which its negative role comes to mind first. He then adds a disclaimer, indicating that underlying tensions need to come to the fore so that the "wheat" may be separated from the "tares."

The situation is an example of what Jesus taught in Matthew 13:

> The kingdom of heaven may be likened to a man who sowed good seed in
> his field. 25 While everyone was asleep his enemy came and sowed
> weeds all through the wheat, and then went off. 26 When the crop
> grew and bore fruit, the weeds appeared as well. 27 The slaves of the
> householder came to him and said, ‘Master, did you not sow good seed
> in your field? Where have the weeds come from?’ 28 He answered, ‘An
> enemy has done this.’ His slaves said to him, ‘Do you want us to go
> and pull them up?’ 29 He replied, ‘No, if you pull up the weeds you
> might uproot the wheat along with them. 30 Let them grow together
> until harvest.

Paul is clearly unhappy about the divisions, but he is confident that in time, the true character of those involved will be made known and dealt with.

Answer (score 3):

Paul employs the analogy of the human body with its various parts in Romans 12:4-5 to illustrate the unity amid diversity within the church, highlighting the diversity of spiritual gifts among its members (Romans 12:6). In Romans 11:17-24, he also employs the imagery of an olive tree with roots representing the church, and its branches symbolizing both Jews and Gentiles, emphasizing their interconnectedness and unity. His message is clear, while acknowledging the differences among members, he emphasizes their essential unity within the body of the church.

In 1 Corinthians 11:17-19, Paul rebuked those who formed divisions among the church, particularly in the context of the communal observance of the Lord's Supper. This sacrament, instituted by Jesus Himself, is meant to be a unifying ritual. However, some members possibly of upper classes, selfishly indulge before others arrive, leaving little on the table for their less fortunate brethren (1 Cor 11:21). Consequently, Paul condemns those people in 1 Cor 11:22;

> do you despise the church of God by humiliating those who have nothing?